# How can I fix my timer algorithm problem?

Tags: vb.net, timer, visual-studio-2017

I wish to find the problem of this code which gives that the application is in break mode Exception unhandled. What can I try?

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred
>   HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error >> > is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
>   Inner Exception 1: NullReferenceException

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim h As Integer = 0, h2 As Integer = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim m As Integer = 0, m2 As Integer = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim s As Integer = 0, s2 As Integer = 60
    Dim m1 As Integer = 0, ml2 As Integer = 100

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer2.Start()
    End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer2.Stop()
    End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Timer2.Stop()
        h2 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        m2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)
        s2 = 60
        ml2 = 100
        Label1.Text = h2 & " : " & m2 & " : " & s2 & " : " & ml2
    End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        ml2 -= 1
        Label1.Text = h2 & " : " & m2 & " : " & s2 & " : " & ml2
        If ml2 = 0 Then
            ml2 = 100
            s2 -= 1
            Label1.Text = h2 & " : " & m2 & " : " & s2 & " : " & ml2
            If s2 = 0 Then
                s2 = 60
                m2 -= 1
                Label1.Text = h2 & " : " & m2 & " : " & s2 & " : " & ml2
                If m2 = 0 Then
                    m2 = 60
                    h2 -= 1
                    Label1.Text = h2 & " : " & m2 & " : " & s2 & " : " & ml2
                    If h2 = 0 Then
                        h2 = 0
                        Timer1.Stop()
                        h2 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
                        m2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)
                        s2 = 60
                        ml2 = 100
                        Label1.Text = h2 & " : " & m2 & " : " & s2 & " : " & ml2
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are trying to access an object that has not been initialized. Aside from the legacy code and the terrible design pattern, nothing jumps out to me why a NullReferenceException would be thrown. Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: You can't assign the value of a textbox to h2 and m2 in the form's declarations section (the area following Public Class Form1). That's the cause of the null reference exception.

Comment: Even if you could do what @HoneyboyWilson mentions, what would be the point, given that the user hasn't entered anything into the `TextBoxes` at that point. Think about WHEN the code you write will be executed and put the right code in the right place to be executed at the right time.

Comment: so where should I get assign the value of textbox to the variables.I want the user to choose the hour and minutes of the timer. please show me the ropes @honeyboy-wilson

Comment: Once the user has entered values into the textboxes then you might retrieve those values and assign them to variables in a button's click event, for example. Or any event the user initiates after supplying values.

Comment: When the form loads the timer hasn't started yet I put the start counting of the timer to a button so why do you say when user hasn't entered anything yet, the time is when I click the first button @jmcilhinney

Comment: I'm not talking about in the `Tick` event handler or the `Click` event handler. I'm talking about the declarations of the `h2` and `m2` fields. Why are you trying to initialise those variables with user input when the controls don't even exist at that point, never mind the user having entered anything into them.

Comment: In `Button3.Click` you assign `h2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)` and `m2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)`. Is this correct, both are the same value? If not edit your question and correct the code.

Comment: In the form's declaration you assign `ml2 As Integer = 100` and again in `Button3.Click` `ml2 = 100`.  In the Timer.Tick ` ml2 -= 1`. Now it is 99. The 2 lines down you check if it is zero. What are you trying to do? I think no thought is happening. You are just writing meaningless code.

Comment: Now, what do you think these 2 lines in `Timer.Tick` mean? `If h2 = 0 Then`  `h2 = 0` If it passes the test that it equals zero why assign 0?

Comment: What line does it error on?

Comment: Just for grins, what is the `Interval` property of the `Timer2`? What ever happened to Timer1?

Comment: The cause is that when you use `h2 As Integer = Val(TextBox1.Text)` ,TextBox1.Text is object variable which are uninitialized. There is no meaningful value available. You can use it in the `Form_Load` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access value of TextBox1 before complete initialization. Just by tweak your code slightly, error goes away.

```
Dim h As Integer = 0, h2 As Integer = 0
Dim m As Integer = 0, m2 As Integer = 0
Dim s As Integer = 0, s2 As Integer = 60
Dim m1 As Integer = 0, ml2 As Integer = 100
```

Set h2 and m2 value at load event of form like as below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load       
    h2 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    m2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: That won't do much good unless the textboxes have values placed in them at design time. Initializing h2 and m2 to those values in the declarations section would make more sense. But your code will get rid of the null reference exception.

Comment: Can I write a better, less syntax and more efficient countdown algorithm without using a lot of if clauses and get all hour, minute and second value from the user. please help @user13422309

Comment: plz elaborate your requirement..@Immortality